# Most Efficient Parser in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, parse-tree

I cannot find a parsing algorithm in NLTK which parses a sentence in a reasonable amount of time when instantiated with a large grammar (training on more than 20 or so fileids of the Penn Treebank results in parses taking several minutes or longer, depending on the parsing algorithm). I am using the entire treebank for training - all ~2,400 fileids - so this much time per sentence is not feasible, since I am trying to parse the whole of the test set of the treebank (fileids 2,300 - 2,399).

The algorithms I have tried so far include:

- ViterbiParser
- All of the ChartParser algorithms
- RecursiveDescentParser (this in fact exits with a RecursionError just after starting)

If there is any algorithm which can parse quickly when trained on a large grammar (even if it is not contained within the NLTK library), I would be grateful to be pointed in this direction.

I am aware of the CoreNLPParser module, however as far as I know this can only be called with a grammar already loaded, which does not meet my requirement as I am looking for an algorithm to assess against the Penn Treebank test set, and therefore need the ability to decide the grammar to be used by the algorithm.

Comment: Have a look at the `spaCy` library: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features

Comment: spaCy only provides a dependency parser, not a standard phrase parser that produces a parse tree like the NLTK algorithms do.

Comment: You can try benepar which will produce the (Constituency parser) tree, it can be used along with spacy. https://spacy.io/universe/?id=self-attentive-parser

Comment: Gideon, do you know if it's possible to use this library to get multiple parse trees for a single sentence? Thanks.

Comment: Tagged [tag:parse-tree]. Also, can anyone post the numbers of the relevant NTLK github issues?

Comment: @ShinzoAbe What worked for u?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try out Benepar ([Berkeley Neural parser](https://spacy.io/universe/project/self-attentive-parser))

It has an MIT License and integrates with NLTK or spaCy. Language support includes:
English, Chinese, German, Basque, French, Hebrew, Hungarian, Korean, Polish, Swedish